# AngularJS - link two select

Tags: angularjs

I want to link two select in angularjs. when first select value in(3,4) the second select show.

code:

```
<select ng-model="type">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<select ng-show="type in [3,4]">
    ...
</select>
```

But it is not work.
Thanks.

Comment: what have you done so far...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is fiddle :-)

http://jsfiddle.net/svbxwphr/

```
  <div ng-controller="AjaxCtrl">
      <h1>AJAX - Oriented</h1>
    <div>
        Country: 
        <select id="country" ng-model="country" ng-options="country for country in ['1','2','3','4']">
          <option value=''>Select</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        City: <select id="city" ng-disabled="!cities" ng-model="city" ng-options="city for city in cities"><option value=''>Select</option></select>

  </div>
```

Controller:-

```
function AjaxCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.$watch('country', function(newVal) {
        if (newVal==3|| newVal==4){ 
            $scope.cities = ['3', '4'];}
        else{
             $scope.cities = [];
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no syntax for **in** in ng-show.

you have to write long syntax.

```
<select ng-model="type">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<select ng-show="type === '3' || type === '4'">
    ...
</select>
```